# What is the skeleton that the MUTOs are first discovered in?

Tags: godzilla-2014, monsterverse

In the 2014 rendition of Godzilla, the new enemy is the MUTOs, which are found to have consumed the radioactive energy from a long dead monster of apparent unknown origin.

My initial assumption was that it might have been King Ghidorah, since the skeleton resembled the long neck, but the length threw me off – resembling something more snakelike (which has since been confirmed by the release of the "King of Monsters" trailer).

The original tease for the movie showed a [completely separate monster](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312002211/https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Unnamed_Multi-Legged_Monster) that was intended as the initial opponent for Godzilla – resembling a tardigrade – but was scrapped, and left unlabelled. Again, I thought perhaps, since this monster was scrapped, the skeleton might be of this monster instead, but again, the skeleton doesn't match up (even if this monster could have a skeleton, since it resembles the tardigrade).

So, is there any information about what this skeleton was, before it was killed by the MUTO parasites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was Dagon, Godzilla’s ancestor who was beaten half to death by the MUTO Prime and implanted with the eggs so they could feed off its energy, it’s in the *Godzilla: Aftershock* book.

> ### History
>
> **Godzilla: Aftershock**
>
> Dagon encountered and fought with the parasitic MUTO Prime. After a brief fight, Dagon was beaten to the brink of death by MUTO Prime, who then proceeded to implant her eggs into Dagon's stomach lining.
>
> **Godzilla**
>
> Dagon's skeleton would be seen following a mine collapse in the Philippines, as would the remains of the eggs laid in him. Ishiro Serizawa would be present, overlooking the creature's massive ribs and a subsequent hole dug out of the mountain wall, with a trail of destruction leading to the ocean.

[Source](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Dagon)

Comment: This appears to be a nice find, could you [edit] in the relevant quote to back it up?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's a new, nondescript monster, simply there to make clear that there have been monsters for a very long time.

[Manda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manda_(kaiju)) is a snakelike Kaiju from the Toho films, and could conceivably be the monster of the remains. However, I suspect they wouldn't want to lose access to any monster for a future film.

Also, it's possible they weren't as interested in planting easter eggs in this first film. Considering they made up new monsters, the MUTOs, to serve as the antagonists in this film, that may be the case. They only wanted to use one "official" monster in that first film. It was only in Kong that they opened up the universe with official Toho monsters, as we'll see in the sequel.

Answer (score -2):

I think it could've been a female version of Godzilla. According to the director, Gareth Edwards, Godzilla's species existed in an era when the Earth was 12 times more radioactive than it is today. The MUTOs were the parasites of that age, feeding on dead Godzillas and laying their eggs inside these corpses to sustain them on their radiation energy. The skeleton we see in the movie could've been a female Godzilla (ostensibly our male Godzilla's mate) who was killed by the MUTOs, and Godzilla is only trying to avenge his mate, as also trying to restore the balance of nature, by working to destroy the two MUTOs.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to support this theory?